# how to get geometric mean for a measure in cube in ssas 2012

Tags: ssas

I have one measure called  StayInHospital in my cube . I want to calculate the geometric mean
  for this measure .
Please see the example

```
Day ,   AccoutNumber , Stayinhospital , VisitCount

1   ,        A1      ,       2         ,   1
1   ,        A2      ,       4         ,   1
1   ,        A3      ,       8         ,   1
```

Geometric Mean for above example for Day 1 for `Stayinhospital` measure = (2*4*8)^1/3

```
                                                           =4
```

I have done the following calculation in Calculated member

```
  Measures.WeightLog as log(StayInHospital)
  Measures.ProductOfWeights as 10^Measures.WeightLog
  Measures.GMLOS as (Measures.ProductOfWeights)^(1/(Measures.VisitCount))
```

I am not getting the expected result.

It is summing the `StayInHospital` Value instead of multiplying
 please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated member formulas are applied after aggregation. Hence the best solution would be to calculate the logarithm already during data loading, e. g. as a named calculation in the Data Source View, e. g. add a calculation with the expression

```
log(StayInHospital) / log(10.0)
```

assuming your relational column is named `StayInHospital`. This expression takes care of the fact that `Log` is for base `e`, not for base `10`, and converts it to a logarithm of base 10.

Then, define a normal summable measure based on this named calculation, named e. g. LogStayInHospital.

Finally, define your measure `GMLOS` as

```
( 10 ^ Measures.LogStayInHospital ) ^ (1 / Measures.VisitCount)
```

or, equivalently, as

```
10 ^ (Measures.LogStayInHospital / Measures.VisitCount)
```

If everything works fine, and you do not need it for debugging any more, you can make the measure `LogStayInHospital` invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `dimensions` look like, so I will asume `AccountNumber` is an attribute in the dimension `Account`.

Now change `[Measures].[WeightLog]` to look like this:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[WeightLog] AS Sum([Account].[AccountNumber].[AccountNumber].MEMBERS, Log([Measures].[StayInHospital]))
```

This should calculate the `Log` for every account and then `Sum` the results.

In [Mosha Pasumansky's blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2006/12/18/how-to-aggregate-values-as-a-product-multiplication-in-mdx.aspx) you can also read about this (He used the DESCENDANTS function but the principle is the same.